# Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Need help Please in MyBank jEE application. the Problem is that hibernate is able to Create the Tables but it doesn't insert the data here is my code

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.sid.dao.ClientRepository;
import org.sid.dao.CompteRepository;
import org.sid.entities.Client;
import org.sid.entities.Compte;
import org.sid.entities.CompteCourant;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyBankApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientrepository;

    @Autowired
    private CompteRepository compteRepository;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MyBankApplication.class, args);
//      ClientRepository clientrepository = ctx.getBean(ClientRepository.class);
//      clientrepository.save(new Client("hassan", "hassan@gmail.com"));
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        Client c1 = clientrepository.save(new Client("Hassan", "hasan@gmail.com"));
        Client c2 = clientrepository.save(new Client("Rachide", "Rachide@gmail.com"));
        Compte cpt = compteRepository.save(new CompteCourant("c1", new Date(), 90000, c1, 5000));
    }

}
```

```css
package org.sid.dao;

import org.sid.entities.Client;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long> {

}
```

```html
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long code;
    private String nom;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Compte> comptes;

    public Client() {
        super();
    }

    public Client(String nom, String email) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Long getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(Long code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Collection<Compte> getComptes() {
        return comptes;
    }

    public void setComptes(Collection<Compte> comptes) {
        this.comptes = comptes;
    }


}
```

Here is the error why it coudn't answer the data to the database

> HHH000230: Schema export complete
>   2017-06-13 17:51:40.270  INFO 73460 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>   2017-06-13 17:51:41.152  INFO 73460 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2eaf2b1: startup date [Tue Jun 13 17:51:30 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   2017-06-13 17:51:41.353  INFO 73460 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
>   2017-06-13 17:51:41.356  INFO 73460 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
>   2017-06-13 17:51:41.440  INFO 73460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   2017-06-13 17:51:41.441  INFO 73460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   2017-06-13 17:51:41.577  INFO 73460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   2017-06-13 17:51:42.822  INFO 73460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
>   2017-06-13 17:51:43.115  INFO 73460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
>   2017-06-13 17:51:43.319  INFO 73460 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
>   Hibernate: insert into client (email, nom) values (?, ?)
>   Hibernate: insert into client (email, nom) values (?, ?)
>   Hibernate: select comptecour0_.code_compte as code_com2_1_0_, comptecour0_.code_cli as code_cli7_1_0_, comptecour0_.date_creation as date_cre3_1_0_, comptecour0_.solde as solde4_1_0_, comptecour0_.decouvert as decouver6_1_0_ from compte comptecour0_ where comptecour0_.code_compte=? and comptecour0_.type_cpte='CC'
>   Hibernate: select client0_.code as code1_0_0_, client0_.email as email2_0_0_, client0_.nom as nom3_0_0_ from client client0_ where client0_.code=?
>   Hibernate: insert into compte (code_cli, date_creation, solde, decouvert, type_cpte, code_compte) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 'CC', ?)
>   2017-06-13 17:51:43.633  INFO 73460 --- [  restartedMain] org.sid.MyBankApplication                : Started MyBankApplication in 15.741 seconds (JVM running for 16.96)
>   2017-06-13 17:51:47.555  INFO 73460 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
>   2017-06-13 17:51:47.555  INFO 73460 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
>   2017-06-13 17:51:47.585  INFO 73460 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 30 ms

:

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate: insert into client (email, nom) values (?, ?) 
Hibernate: insert into client (email, nom) values (?, ?)